# http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in

Tags: php, ssl, copy, fopen

The "allow_url_fopen" property of the php.ini file is "On". But in the "copy ()" function I get this error.

"[14-Aug-2017 08:42:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  copy(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/timforkl/public_html/test.php on line 3
[14-Aug-2017 08:42:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  copy(http://mitforklift.com/dealers/shared/images/imglib/ESDN3-34SHEETPRODUCT-PAGE-01-S.jpg): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/timforkl/public_html/test.php on line 3 "

test.php ►

```
if(copy("http://mitforklift.com/dealers/shared/images/imglib/ESDN3-34SHEETPRODUCT-PAGE-01-S.jpg","gok.jpg")){
echo 'sa';
}
else{
echo'as'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart your server machine or services in order to reload php.ini file.